# How to set readonly / disabled input via php?

Tags: php, html, forms, input, disabled-input

I have a form that allows the user to change name, surname, password etc. So, I have an email field disabled, I don't want to allow the user to change the email in the account settings, so I disabled the input with the disabled html parameter. However, it can be easily bypassed, just go to google console and delete the disabled parameter in the html to change the email input and send the request.

I cannot create a fake email field as the form communicates with a plugin, so the email input must necessarily be present. I thought about disabling it with php as this can't be seen in the html but I'm not sure how to do it and I'm not sure if it's the right method.

How could I disable the form input making it inaccessible to the user and prevent it from being modified with some cheating?

```
<form name="Form" class="mts-edit-account" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" <?php add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag', 'action_woocommerce_edit_account_form_tag' );?> >

  <div class="form-row email_show">
    <label class="t3" for="disabled_account_email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="field-settings disabled" style="pointer-events:none;" name="account_email" id="account_email" disabled value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->user_email ); ?>" />  
    <span class="t4-light">Description..........</span>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: You can change the `type` to hidden .. It's not bulletproof .. But will keep honest people honest ..  If you REALLY need it bulletproof .. Set it as a `$_SESSION` variable and then call it in the plugin ..

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I need it to be visible, can it work with $ _SESSION? If so, are there any references? Because I don't know where to start.

Comment: Take it out of the input and just show it in a DIV -- AND use  `$_SESSION['user_email] = esc_attr( $user->user_email )` -- You will have to tweak your plugin to look for that session variable .. But it's the most secure way.  But since you're using a plugin .. It might already be set ..  I would `print_r( $_SESSION );` and see what session vars are stored already ..

Comment: _"How could I disable the form input making it inaccessible to the user and prevent it from being modified with some cheating?"_ - If you really need to send the email from the client to your backend (and you don't control that backend), then there isn't that many ways you can truly lock it down. At the end of the day, the user will have access (and will be able to) change anything in the frontend (HTML/JS). You can never trust data that comes from a client.

Comment: You can disable the form field as any other form field, and there's no need to handle that field's input in PHP in any way

Answer (score 1):

Your requirements are, unfortunately, impossible due to the design of the web - your code can not *control* what the user can do, it can only *suggest* what they should do, and *detect* what they have done.

> I cannot create a fake email field as the form communicates with a plugin, so the email input must necessarily be present.

If you want the the user's browser to send data directly to the plugin, then **that data is under the user's control**. If necessary, the user can write an entire HTML form of their own, and submit that; or just use a script to create a request that looks indistinguishable from one a real browser would generate.

So, you are right that you need to do something on the server-side, but that needs to be **after the form is submitted**, not before. For instance:

- before passing the data to the plugin, overwrite the value of this field in the `$_POST` array (or whatever form the input takes at the point you intercept it) with the required value
- rather than letting the plugin handle the form directly, write your own form handling code that manipulates the data, then call some function in the plugin directly with your manipulated data

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I will try to follow your advice. The plugin I'm talking about is woocommerce, so the form I'm trying to edit belongs to the form-edit-account.php template. Actually I can insert a fake email field and delete the original one, but if I send an ajax request to save the form I get an error because the ajax script expects to find the original field which doesn't exist since I deleted it. So here I was thinking about leaving the original field and disabling it somehow that can't be bypassed.

Comment: @Snorlax As I say in the answer, the code you need to look at is not what **generates** the form, but what **receives** it - the page that processes the form when it's submitted, or receives the AJAX request when it's sent. There is no such thing as "disabling in a way that can't be bypassed".